# Windows Mixed Reality - AttachToController

Tags: c#, windows-mixed-reality

So I'm using the AttachToController script to attach a window floated on top of the controller - which works great. In the script that calls up the window, I figure out which hand pressed the controller's menu button and set the Handedness field appropriately (Left or Right). The problem I'm trying to solve is this: Let's say the user clicks on the right controller's menu button and then later on, the left menu button is clicked. The problem I'm experiencing is that even though I've altered the Handedness field, the window still appears attached to the right controller.

```
private void InteractionManager_InteractionSourcePressed(InteractionSourcePressedEventArgs args)
{
    hand = args.state.source.handedness;
    ...
}

private void SetHandednessAndActivate(GameObject go)
{
    AttachToController script = go.GetComponentInChildren<AttachToController>();
    if (script != null)
    {
        script.Handedness = hand;           
    }
    go.SetActive(true);
}
```

Just to be clear, if the user clicks the left controller menu button first, the window is always on the left and the same holds true for the right controller. What I want is for the window to move to whichever controller is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
script.Handedness = hand;
```

Use

```
script.ChangeHandedness(hand);
```

All the other bits are handled by the script.